# Docker app does not read daily updated data

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, shiny, dockerfile

I have developed a docker app that reads data from a folder on my server (/myapp1/app/data). The data are updated daily in this folder. If I run the docker app on my domain, the app reads the data from the folder, but when these data are updated the app doesn't read the new data, it only reads the old data. If I down the container and run it again, then the app does read the new data.

My dockerfile is the following:

```
# get shiny server and R from the rocker project
FROM rocker/shiny:4.0.5

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    gdebi-core \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libxml2 \
    libxml2-dev \
    libsodium-dev

# install R packages required 
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('shiny', 'shinythemes', 'dygraphs', 'shinyWidgets', 'manipulateWidget', 'DT', 'zoo', 'shinyjs','emayili', 'wordcloud2', 'rmarkdown', 'xts', 'shinyauthr', 'curl', 'jsonlite', 'httr', 'lubridate'), repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"


# copy the app directory into the image
WORKDIR /myapp1/app
COPY app .

# run app
EXPOSE 8090
CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/myapp1/app',  host = '0.0.0.0', port = 8090)"]
```

My docker-compose.yml file is the following:

```
version: "3.7"

services:

 app1:
  image: myapp1image
  container_name: myapp1container
  expose:
   - "8090"
  environment:
   - VIRTUAL_PORT=8090
   - VIRTUAL_HOST=myapp1.net,www.myapp1.net
   - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=myapp1.net,www.myapp1.net
   - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=info@myapp1.net  
  volumes:
   - /myapp1/app/data:/myapp1/app/data
  networks:
   - mynetwork

networks:
 mynetwork:
  external : true
```

My app should read the updated data without having to down and run the container every time the data is updated, so I would appreciate a solution to the problem raised above.

Comment: Where in your application code do you actually read the data? It sounds like maybe you just read it at startup and don't ever check for new data. This doesn't sound like it has anything to do with docker specifically.

Comment: When the shiny app runs on localhost, it reads the data when the app is opened on the browser. The app consists of two codes: app.R and global.R. The first reads the second, which loads the data and functions. I believe the solution is to modify the code so that it continuously reads the data.

Comment: You would need to modify the app.R or global.R code then. There's nothing you would change in the docker or docker compose file. If you ran the application outside of docker, you would seem the same behavior. Some ideas how to fix that are here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/automatically-updating-shiny-data-for-all-users-every-week/73215/2

Comment: Thanks! I'll modify the code so that it reads the data once a day, after the data are refreshed